# Can ocamlc can compiler file other than ml and mli?

Tags: ocaml

I know ocamlc can compiler ocaml source file .ml and .mli

I am reading the compiler source code 4.07,in driver/pparse.ml,the function file_aux will use ocamlyacc to got the ast Parsetree.

in line 169:

```
File: d:\src\ocaml-4.07.0\driver\pparse.ml
169:   let (ic, is_ast_file) = open_and_check_magic inputfile ast_magic in
```

will check is the file is a ast file.I want to know what file will be the astfile?

I can write this code to cheak it:

```
Printf.printf "%b" is_ast_file
```

but when i use both .ml and .mli file,all got false.Is the astfile means .cmt file?

I think the astfile here is the .cmt file.I can use ocamlc option -bin-annot to got a .cmt file.Is it the .cmt file?but I can't use ocamlc to compiler a .cmt file.Thanks!

Comment: This is your second question on the `ocamlc` compiler. Are you trying to accomplish something in particular or are you just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `.cmt` file. A `.cmt` file contains more information than just the AST.

This AST magic is used for preprocessors that allow to write alternative syntaxes to the language. See the description of the `-pp` option in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html). See [Camlp4](https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4) for an example of use of this functionality.

Note that the file produced by the call of `-pp` will only be a temporary one (unless there is an error).

To answer the question in your title, the file extensions the `ocamlc` compiler can read are `.ml`, `.mli`, `.cmo` (compiled module), `.cmi` (compiled interface) and `.cma` (compiled library).